# Live search a websql table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a websql table with approximately 2500 rows, each with a unique text value. I want the user to be able to search these and select one using javascript/jquery.

I should stress that I'm doing this on mobile and not desktop.

I can easily do a text match search, but what I really wanted was to achieve something similar to the "standard select" on this plugin https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ where the list is filtered on each keystroke.

Comment: What have you written so far?  Where is it failing?

Comment: Should probably delete this question, worked it out. But thanks.